# Array: How to change specific values dependent on index (Rating function)

Tags: arrays, vue.js, indexing, toggle, rating

I'm sorry for the terrible title, but somehow I can't explain it better in one sentence.

What I want to do is a rating component in my Vue App. So if I click the 3rd star, the two stars before that one are set to "true" as well.

What I got:

```
const ratingsArray = [
  {
    name: 'rating1',
    ratingCount: 1,
    isClicked: ref(false)
  },
  {
    name: 'rating2',
    ratingCount: 2,
    isClicked: ref(false)
  },
  {
    name: 'rating3',
    ratingCount: 3,
    isClicked: ref(false)
  },
  {
    name: 'rating4',
    ratingCount: 4,
    isClicked: ref(false)
  },
  {
    name: 'rating5',
    ratingCount: 5,
    isClicked: ref(false)
  },
]
```

I just got a toggle function to toggle `isClicked`:

```
function toggleClick(x) {
  x.value = !x.value
}
```

This is my template

```
<template>
    <div v-for="rating in ratingsArray" 
     :key="rating.name" 
     @click="toggleClick(rating.isClicked)" 
     :class="[rating.isClicked.value ? 'ratingBoxFilled' : 'ratingBox']">
    </div>
</template>
```

How can I say, that if `rating3` is clicked (so `isClicked` is true), rating1 and rating2 also got to be true?

It seems that I need to work with the index in my array. But somehow, I cannot create an idea. Maybe you guys can help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop would do the trick:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(rating, index) in ratingsArray" 
     :key="rating.name" 
     @click="toggleClick(index)" 
     :class="[rating.isClicked.value ? 'ratingBoxFilled' : 'ratingBox']">
    </div>
</template>

function toggleClick(ratingIndex) {
  for (let i = 0; i < ratingsArray.length; i++) {
    // Set ratingsArray[i].isClicked to true if it's within the requested range
    ratingsArray[i].isClicked.value = (i <= ratingIndex);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are so great, god bless you dude

Comment: @mikasa This code will not work if user selects `5th star` first and then try to select `3rd star`. As first time it will mark `isClicked` true for all the objects and when user will click on 3rd star it will make isClicked false for first `3 stars` which is not a correct and desired behaviour of rating system.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal That is a very good point, thanks! Updated my answer.

Comment: Great! Now, I hope it will work as per author expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are great. I didn't thought of an for loop.
So here is my final solution:

```
<div 
 v-for="(rating, index) in ratingsArray" 
 :key="rating.name" 
 @click="updateRating(index, rating.ratingValue)" 
 :class="[rating.isEnabled.value ? 'ratingBoxChecked' : 'ratingBox']">
</div>
```

```
function updateRating(ratingIndex: number, ratingValue: number) {
  for (let i = ratingIndex; i < 5; i++) {
    ratingsArray[i].isEnabled.value = false;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i <= ratingIndex; i++) {
    ratingsArray[i].isEnabled.value = true;
  }

  console.log('Rating Value: ' + ratingValue)
}
```

First I clean all the enabled dots.
Then it will run until the given index and set the boolean value to true. Thats all.